# React native I'm suffering this problem sometimes in react native and I couldn't find a solution yet

Tags: react-native

Sometimes this error appears

> Error: Requiring unknown menter code hereodule "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`., js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
> A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes`

[image]

my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.9.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.9.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^14.9.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.16",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.7",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.4.0",
    "@shopify/restyle": "^2.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.3.1",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "i18next": "^22.0.8",
    "jsc-android": "^294992.0.0",
    "lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
    "luxon": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.3",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "^5.5.8",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
    "react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.14.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.12",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^5.46.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.9",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^37.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.4.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-circus": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-junit": "^15.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  }
```

I still couldn't find solutions to this problem, I already tried to map it in the flipper but the same log appears

Comment: Have you tried to run `gradlew clean` in android folder and removing `node_modules` and running `npm i`. Also, do not forget to uninstall application from test device or emulator